# jQuery Mind Map/Think Map

Tags: javascript, jquery, mindmapping

I was wondering if anyone happens to know of a jQuery (or pure javascript) mind map.  I found [this one](http://kenneth.kufluk.com/google/js-mindmap/) a few times, but it uses MooTools, unfortunately.

Comment: I'm betting you'll need to rewrite it using jQuery.ui

Answer (score 58, accepted):

I decided to port the [one you found](https://github.com/kennethkufluk/js-mindmap) into a jQuery plugin, which can be found LINK REMOVED - SEE EDIT.

**Edit:** I've contacted the author of the original Mindmap, and my jQuery conversion has become the core of development.  You can get it, as well as speed improvements and new functionality [here](https://github.com/kennethkufluk/js-mindmap), on the Github page.

Comment: There were a couple minor issues, but it's worked well so far.  Thanks!

Comment: It does actually work in IE8, but extremely sluggishly. If you hit F12 to get the Dev Tools open, then refresh the page it'll work fine. It's only failing at the moment because the example uses console.log's

Comment: Great mind map @MikeTrpcic, im trying to use images for the nodes with  `list-style-image: url('/tuin.jpg');` with no luck. Ill appreciate your help, tahnks!

Comment: This is good, but it doesn't seem to work with more than one layer of nodes.

Answer (score 29):

I think you should try http://thejit.org/

I use it all the time and is perfect for my needs.

Answer (score 5):

There's also [arbor.js](https://github.com/samizdatco/arbor), much newer then the ones cited in other answers. It implements the force directed algorithm for layout, similar to js-mindmap that you cited, but with better performance since it uses webworkers. The actual rendering is left for you, so you can use jquery or whatever you prefer.

Answer (score 4):

Also, if you decide to write your own implementation, a good visualization library is [d3.js](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/).

Answer (score 2):

I wrote [this one](http://marcodiiga.github.io/knode/) for a project, it's an enhanced jQuery plugin version of other js node maps I found online suitable for dynamic contents (i.e. also supports dynamic adding/removal of nodes, selection marks, customizable callbacks and styles).

Notice: IE wasn't in the compatibility targets since it's also [officially being dropped](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/technology/microsoft/11479427/Microsoft-drops-Internet-Explorer-brand.html)

Comment: I know I might be a little late to the party, but thank you! Your plugin is very nice :) You have a pull request pending ;)