# How to mimic this effect

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I found the exact match for what I'm looking for, it's kind of a relationship user interface, please see

http://www.corporationwiki.com/Ohio/Powell/nutrition-forum-sports-llc/50101823.aspx

[image: Screenshot of relationship visualizer]

Ho do I mimic that, I need to code a php aplication that retrieves relations from a database and displays them like that above, so that I have 1 (or many) center nodes, and several others around it pointing and linked to that node, displayed like that above.

Best Regards

PS: I will need to add and remove nodes "on the fly" live, like with jquery and ajax/json calls.

I see I was voted down, I'm sorry if this is not the place to ask this I will gladly retract my question. Can you then please be so kind to point me the place where to ask for this type of information instead of voting me down on my first question ever here?

Comment: On SO developers help developers. What have you tried and issues have you experienced?

Comment: I agree with Zerkms. But if i were you starting with a static model of the relationship visualiser thingy would be a easier task. Try that first.

Comment: I've found this http://asterisq.com/products/constellation/roamer but I need an opensource solution,

Comment: yes but I can do it staticly and I've already started coding it, what I need is an interface like that one I posted, but free

Comment: Did you do some research? If you did you would have found out that this relationship visualizer is FLASH! I guess that nobody can give you the php code for that. Learn Action script instead. And if you want to make this in php you got to be creative yourself, we can't just give you some code you copy from here and past in your file...

Comment: Have a look here: [jQuery Mind Map](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374149/jquery-mind-map-think-map/1379177#1379177) which also points to [thejit](http://thejit.org/demos/)

Answer (score 1):

Here are some suggestions, although the get more specific the comments above still apply.

- Start with a simple test case, with just one centre node and a few child nodes. If something works in an easy case, move on to the next level of complexity and so on.
- Whatever you try, expect the esthetics/clarity of your graph to break down when you reach a certain level of compexity - nodes will overlap, not appear where you want them, etc., so don't expect too much.
- Look for a library that would help. In flash, several graph layouts must have been implemeted before. In Javascript too, there are drawing panel libraries, or you could use a library for SVG or... Look for something that suits. As a comment above says, PHP is probably not it.

Answer (score 1):

Neo4J (Graph Database) is implemented in Java and should be capable of what you show in the image. I haven't had an opportunity to use it for anything, but it looks powerful, simple, and is open source (with good documentation). 
Also, try doing a search for Relationship Mapping and you may find what your looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [GraphViz](http://www.graphviz.org/) for drawing *static* boxes and connecting them with arrow-headed lines. It has a very simple script (the shortest one is: "*start -> stop*", self-explanatory).

Some years ago I've made an XML file tree visualizer in PHP:[image: xmlgraph].
As the figure shown, there's some kind of HTML table-like feature to draw a node. See GraphViz [Gallery](http://www.graphviz.org/Gallery.php) for some more exciting examples.

**Update**: As I mentioned, it's only for static, but you can make an app very quickly which displays the stuff. I've used my XML visualizer to make drawings for documentation.