# HTML 5 / Javascript flowchart tools / prezi style?

Tags: html, mapping, visualization, relational, prezi

Does anyone know if there is sort of an open-source Prezi tool that works with HTML5 / javascript? I'm looking for a way to set up a flow-chart diagram and then have the browser window focus on different parts of it. Rotation and cool effects not necessary but welcomed.

RaVis looks cool, but it is flash based: http://code.google.com/p/birdeye/wiki/RaVis ([example here](http://birdeye.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ravis/RaVisExamples/example-binaries/RaVisExplorer.html))

Another post mentions [Raphael Graffle](https://dmitrybaranovskiy.github.io/raphael/graffle.html), which is cool, but not exactly what I'm looking for.

Diagramo ([site](http://diagramo.com/)  & [example](http://diagramo.com/)) is cool, but I want to create a standalone version on my webpage, possibly with some interaction.

[Eignfactor](http://eigenfactor.org/map/) is also pretty cool, but is is flash based.

Found a good jQuery library for visualization too: http://thejit.org/demos/

Two more:

[jQuery Mind Map/Think Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374149/jquery-mind-map-think-map)

[Javascript or JQuery mindmap plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/565081/javascript-or-jquery-mindmap-plugin)

Would love to see what suggestions you guys have and / or similar cool examples you've seen.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**[impress.js](https://github.com/impress/impress.js)** is *"a presentation framework based on the power of CSS3 transforms and transitions in modern browsers and inspired by the idea behind prezi.com"*.

Through the use of HTML 5 "data-*" attributes, one easily describes the positioning, panning, rotation or scaling operations to be applied as a transition when jumping from one slide to another. Some 3D effects are even available...

An "impressive" **[online demonstration](http://impress.github.io/impress.js)** is  available.

Comment: very nice. looking forward to playing with this!

Comment: If you don't want to hand code your impress.js presentations check out http://strut.io

Answer (score 3):

Try this: http://janne.aukia.com/zoomooz/

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old topic, but I created Presenteer.js ( http://willemmulder.github.com/Presenteer.js/ ) recently, which seems to do exactly what you asked for. You (or others that view this topic) might want to have a look at it...

Answer (score 0):

The best Prezi-like presentation tool using HTML5 & SVG and seamlessly working in iOS is [Awwation](http://adityab.github.com/Awwation/).

Have a look at the [demo presentation](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/40496552/Presentations/aww/presentation.svg).

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same thing. This blog post describes an open-source tool called Sozi, which is a plugin for Inkscapes. The post links to a presentation created with it that plays on all browsers, including iPad, EXCEPT IE. Even IE 10. Bummer.

http://blog.lightcastletech.com/2013/04/18/prezi-vs-inkscapes-sozi/