# Is there plugins for mind mapping?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, mindmapping

Are there jQuery or JavaScript libraries or plugins for writing something like [mind-mapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mind_map)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery Mind Map/Think Map](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374149/jquery-mind-map-think-map)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try looking on this: http://www.headjump.de/article/arrows-and-boxes

It is jQuery library which transforms right syntax into mind-map-like graphs

More libraries you should like:
http://code.google.com/p/js-mindmap/
http://www.yworks.com/en/products_yfilesajax_about.html
http://www.kylescholz.com/blog/projects/jsviz/

Answer (score 7):

See if one of these is OK:

http://code.google.com/p/jsplumb/

http://www.mxgraph.com/mxgraph.html

I have two more, but it won't let me post more than two links. I'll see if it allows a second answer with the other two.  If not check my Twitter stream @roygrubb

Comment: added your links from twt stream to my answer, to have it here