# How to integrate Mind map in Asp.net C#

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, mindmapping

I have some very exciting requirement from the client. Client does not want me to display the results in grid based layout(it looks like a database to him) rather he want me to display the results in some Mind-map way. I have googled some Mind mapping software but they seems to be stand alone software. Can anyone point me to the direction where i can have some Jquery plugin in which i need to pass the data in json etc and it build a mind map for me .

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You may figure out something useful here: [Is there plugins for mind mapping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7460251/is-there-plugins-for-mind-mapping?rq=1)

If not, you may try:

[Mindmup](https://github.com/mindmup/mapjs) Or
[Infovis](http://philogb.github.io/jit/)