# There is some Javascript API to development of mindmaps?

Tags: javascript, api, mindmapping

I'm on a contest with a team. At the moment, I doing some research and I want to find something that can help the creation of mind maps.

There is some Javascript API that can do this?

I need an API where can I add nodes in real-time, not only for visualization.

**EDIT**: The APIs in the related questions is only for visualization.

Comment: Possible duplicate (if you can use jQuery): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374149/jquery-mind-map-think-map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

http://thejit.org/

Or

http://code.google.com/p/js-mindmap/