# JQuery - dynamically generate a graphic tree-view from data

Tags: jquery, treeview

i want to dynamically generate a tree-view to represent a users connections in an applicaiton but i don't want it to look like a normal tree-view (looks like a File System structure) like this:

[image]

but more like a flow-chart like this:

[image]

so basically i want to display it more graphically than a tree-view and if possible - being able to zoom in and out.

how can this be achieved? do you know of any (JS or Jquery) tools for that sort of thing?

thanks

**EDIT:**

in order not to get scattered here're are the tools that seem to be exactly what i was llooking for (with the help of [m90](https://stackoverflow.com/users/797194/m90) and [Tats_innit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1210059/tats-innit))

[thejit](http://thejit.org/)

[d3.js](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/)

[js-mindmap](http://code.google.com/p/js-mindmap/)

[jOrgChart](https://github.com/wesnolte/jOrgChart)

(b.t.w - i'm going with `thejit` for now)

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374149/jquery-mind-map-think-map

Comment: this is not a tutorial site. did you tried anything

Comment: thank you, Chamika Sandamal, for your extremely helpful comment.
i've looked at about a dozen of tools but none of them have the graphic qualities that i'm looking for. so i thought that someone here  might know of such a tool.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for - plugin to create tree view:

[links below]

http://jquery.bassistance.de/treeview/demo/

http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/treeview

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Treeview/treeview

Ah, for the flowchart feel there are few plugin like a link above but try this:

http://code.google.com/p/js-mindmap/

hope this helps, cheers,

Comment: +1 for your question; Try this please, http://code.google.com/p/js-mindmap/ I have edited my post. If you will go to read me section in github link will take you to a demo page http://kenneth.kufluk.com/google/js-mindmap/ , cheers

Answer (score 3):

You can use [JsTree](http://www.jstree.com/). There is also a [tree component](http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12138128/Tree) planed for jQuery UI.

Comment: like i tried to demonstrate with the images in my question - i'm looking for something a little different graphically-wise than the standard tree-views. but thanks