# Create dynamic tree with two levels

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tree

I want to create a tree using jQuery but do not know how and where to start. I drew something below how I want to look your tree.[image]

So I have main root, first level with fixed data and second level with expandable section in which I will display more information.
If anyone can help me with an small js or other html/css method I will be grateful.
Ty and have a great year :).

Answer (score 1):

Some helpful links:

http://th3silverlining.com/2011/12/01/jquery-org-chart-a-plugin-for-visualising-data-in-a-tree-like-structure/

[How to generate a tree for MLM ( Multi-Level Marketing ) in JavaScript for either JSON / XML data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4476442/how-to-generate-a-tree-for-mlm-multi-level-marketing-in-javascript-for-eithe)

[JQuery - dynamically generate a graphic tree-view from data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9653881/jquery-dynamically-generate-a-graphic-tree-view-from-data)